# PHPStorm "Collecting files" for ages on deploy

Tags: php, deployment, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

All of a sudden my PHPStorm has started to collect files extremely slow. It's impossible for me to deploy using PHPStorm now. It just stays "Collecting files" for 5-10 minutes every time I deploy anything. Even if it's just one file

[image]

I asked on the forums, but no answer. It has been reported as a bug by someone but nothing happens there. It's a Laravel project, don't know if that has any effect.

It just started out of nothing.
Here's my Deployment options (nothing is changed)
[image]

My connection is 100mbit and healthy, the server I'm uploading to is quick. No problem there.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried a reinstall of PHPStorm?

Comment: Enable extra logging and see if there will anything interesting there. It could be firewall/ftp server specific config... https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Answer (score 3):

I'm using 2016.1 and have the same issue.  It's not any particular file/directory that I've noticed but what fixed it for me is changing the 'compare by' method in the 'Diff Between' window from 'content' to 'size and timestamp'.

Comment: Unfortunately, this changes the behaviour of the compare. Of course, comparing "content" is slower than only comparing "size and timestamp", but the problem remains: what did change that slowed down something that was working perfectly before?

Answer (score 0):

I got some increase in the speed of connection/checking/collecting files by activating the `Passive mode` in the `Advanced options` window in the Deployment/FTP server options:

[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [erenor.net](http://erenor.net/immagini_hostate/phpstorm-advanced-options.png))</sub>